# How to see (EC)DHE length in a browser?

Tags: tls, web-browser

If you check a site's TLS encryption in a browser, you'll see somethng like `TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`. You can see there AES and SHA length. You can see RSA/EC length if you inspect the certificate. But where can I find (EC)DHE length?

Comment: On Chrome/Chromium at least, you can look at the security section in the developer tools. It will say that it uses, for example, P-384. No idea for Firefox. I haven't seen anything like that myself.

Comment: In a browser? Good question. Dunno. But it’s there when you use openssl s_client with the “-msg” switch.

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff: for 1.0.2 up (the only versions now supported upstream) it's in default `s_client` output under `Server Temp Key:` without needing to decode the message(s). (ALL:) Also for a site _on the Internet_ the SSLLabs report includes this datum along with _many_ others -- and is viewed in your browser, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

The answer will of course depend on which browser you're using. Here are the two that I have available:

## Chrome

This is easy to get; open Developer Tools (F12) > Security tab.

I can see that my browser negotiated curve X25519 (which if you [look up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519)is a 256-bit curve offering 128-bits of security) when I connect to security.stackexchange.com:

[image: Chrome Dev tools Security tab showing the cipher suite and elliptic curve chosen]

Good question whether the key length for traditional DHE would show here also, I don't know of a site that's still using DHE on which I could test...

## Firefox

The Dev Tools (F12) doesn't have a Security tab, and clicking More Information on the green lock tells me the cipher suite was negotiated, but not which curve:

[image: Firefox Site Security > More Information]

A few minutes of googling did not find me a way to get the (EC)DHE info. I'm actually surprised that I can't find a firefox add-on to do it either. You've got me stumped there.

## Other browsers

You'll have to play around in the dev tools and see if it's exposed.

---

The upcoming TLS1.3 is trying to simplify cipher suited by moving more information out of the cipher suite string and into extensions field the same way the size of elliptic curve is negotiated today. So I expect that once Firefox starts using TLS1.3 by default, they will have to add some sort of viewer for this data.

Comment: Chrome no longer negotiates (or supports) suites using non-EC DHE, which can only be <=1.2 because as you say 1.3 removes kx from the suite; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51889831/2868801 at the bottom. I don't know if this will change for 1.3 with standardized rather than server-chosen groups; my current 68.0.3440.106 proactively offers key_share only for x25519 but I don't have a 1.3 server to see what else if any can be elicited.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Do you mean Chrome rejects connection if the server does not support (EC)DHE? Any proof?

Comment: @SmitJohnth: no, I mean(t) for TLS<=1.2 Chrome does not offer suites with non-EC = Mike's 'traditional' = Zp DHE, or as 7919 now calls it FFDHE; it only offers ECDHE and plainRSA. Handshake with a server that _requires_ Zp DHE will fail. For proof, take a net or server trace and look at the ClientHello message. On rechecking I realized that while it only _pushes_ x25519 in key_shares, it also sends supported_groups containing (other than a dummy entry) only x25519 p256 p384, confirming it does not support Zp DHE in 1.3 either. (And 1.3 does not allow plainRSA at all.)

Comment: What is Zp and FFDHE?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 He's using math-speak. Zp DHE = "DHE over integers mod p" = "Finite Field DHE" = "traditional DHE". Basically, different names for the older diffie-hellman that's based on prime numbers, as opposed to the newer ECDSA which is based on Elliptic Curves.

Comment: Mike: I think you meant to ping @Smit not me -- and to contrast with ECDHE not ECDSA :-)

Comment: lol yes to both. That's what I get for trying to multi-task. @SmitJohnth

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I don't think "math speak" belongs to security.se if it can be said with other words.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 "Chrome no longer negotiates (or supports) suites using non-EC DHE" - sounds like "Chrome rejects connection if the server does not support (EC)DHE".

Comment: @SmitJohnth: to me it sounds like 'doesn't support DHE that is not ECDHE'. (It's not really rejection, because the client speaks first, so the server has no chance to offer an unsupported keyexchange.) If I say I won't wear a non-purple hat, it means when I do wear a hat it must be purple, but I can also not wear any hat at all. Of course, as I said _for 1.3_ it does support _only_ ECDHE (counting X25519 as ECDH, which 1.3 does, although it uses a different implementation of EC namely Montgomery).